# Trouble getting JSON response from API in C# MVC

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

I'm currently struggling trying to get a simple response client-side from my MVC API method.
Here is my C# Controller Class:

```
public class LogController : ApiController
{

    private static ConcurrentBag<StreamWriter> clients1;
    private static Random random;
    private static Timer timer;

    static LogController()
    {
        clients1 = new ConcurrentBag<StreamWriter>();
        clients2 = new ConcurrentBag<StreamWriter>();

        timer = new Timer();
        timer.Interval = 1000;
        timer.AutoReset = true;
        timer.Elapsed += timer_ElapsedY1;
        timer.Start();

        random = new Random();

    }

    private async static void timer_ElapsedY1(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        var price = 1.0 + random.NextDouble(); // random number between 1 and 2

        foreach (var client in clients1)
        {
            try
            {
                var data = string.Format("data: {0}\n\n", price);
                await client.WriteAsync(data);
                await client.FlushAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                StreamWriter ignore;
                clients1.TryTake(out ignore);
            }
        }
    }

    [EnableCors(origins: "http://localhost:50322", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetY1(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        var response = request.CreateResponse();
        response.Content = new PushStreamContent((a, b, c) =>
        { OnStreamAvailableY1(a, b, c); }, "text/event-stream");
        return response;
    }


    private void OnStreamAvailableY1(Stream stream, HttpContent content,
        TransportContext context)
    {
        var client = new StreamWriter(stream);
        clients1.Add(client);
    }}}
```

In my client I'm simply trying to do:

```
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://localhost:56495/api/Log/GetY1",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    },
    error: function (msg) { alert('error')}
});
```

I've first faced the problem related with enabling CORS and now I no longer get any error related with allowing acess to the API from the localhost however now I do not get any sort of result from the ajax request whatsoever. I'm trying to figure what I'm doing wrong but so far left without any more clues.

Comment: if you put a breakpoint in when debugging, does your method get hit?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by this code. Could you explain the objective of this program. I guess you want to call the static LogController everytime you post a Get Ajax. I think that wont be possible since static constructors are called only once. Place the code inside the static constructor in a non static method and try